# Computed column vs Updates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if there any performance boost for computed columns in SQL Server, please check the example below.

Now I have a stored procedure in production environment that updates tables, concatenating two `VARCHAR` columns into another column, which is `NULL` when created.

If I would like to switch the updating logic to using a computed column, which will automatically generate the value when loading the data.

Question is: will this help me to boost the process time for that derived column? I cannot really make the changes and test in the production environment at this point, but before I do that, in general, any advantages using computed columns vs updates.

Please note the updated column will remain as it is and the total number of records in effect will be up to million.

**UPDATES:**

Table definition

```
CREATE TableA
(
    ColumnA VARCHAR(50),
    ColumnB VARCHAR(50),
    ColumnC VARCHAR(50)
)
```

`ColumnA` and `ColumnB` will be populated with data from SSIS package, and `ColumnC` will updated by the stored procedure, which is

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET ColumnC = ISNULL(ColumnA,'') + ISNULL(ColumnB,'')
```

These updates will affect about up to millions of records.

If I would like to use:

```
CREATE TableA
(
    ColumnA VARCHAR(50),
    ColumnB VARCHAR(50),
    ColumnC as ISNULL(ColumnA,'') + ISNULL(ColumnB,'') 
)
```

will this be quicker for populating the `ColumnC`?

Comment: Your question doesn't have any details. It is not clear what you are asking or what you are trying to do at all. How about posting the table definition and an explanation of what you want to accomplish? That would be clear instead of vague and broad descriptions.

Comment: Where is "the example below"? You seem to have left out the relevant bits. In *general*, when not persisted in an index, a computed column behaves just as if you'd written `SELECT x = <computation>` in every query that references `x`. That should allow you to estimate what the impact is, and profiling should allow you to *measure* what the impact is.

Comment: Why do you need to store redundant info that will always need to be maintained? Sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that is just an example

Comment: So what value are you computing per row that you need to *store* and *maintain*? Is it not still redundant? What actual problem are you solving?

Comment: it is a key column, and there are certain operations based on that key across different tables, you do not really want to calculate it for every manipulation, and that column will be indexed.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Computed columns aren't the ideal solution for every single manipulation you ever do to data, so I'm just challenging the notion that there is even a problem to solve here, that's all.

Comment: The major advantage to a persisted computed column versus a manual update is consistency: it's literally impossible to have the column be a value that doesn't match its definition. The same is not true for a column that allows independent updates. Performance-wise, the major difference is that a persisted computed column is (necessarily) filled on an `INSERT`, whereas a separate column need not be. Whether that's good or bad depends on your application, though. (In general it's good, because growing a column afterwards incurs page splits and fragmentation.) As always: *measure*.

Comment: Thank you, @AaronBertrand, I did not find any article about this and before tesing, there will be certain number of changes and works. May simulate on my local

Comment: @JeroenMostert, can I understand that like the computed column is still doing the string concatenation in internal but just force a strict pattern to ensure the data consistence?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Of course there are other alternatives, like not using a column at all (performing the calculation in the query or in a view). This does not have the consistency issue either, and may or may not be worth it performance-wise compared to storing/indexing that data. I was trying to get at why the OP is convinced that a computed column is the solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the update I suggest a where so you don't update rows that do not need to be updated.  An update takes a lock and puts an entry in the transaction log.

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET   ColumnC  = ISNULL(ColumnA,'') + ISNULL(ColumnB,'') 
WHERE ColumnC <> ISNULL(ColumnA,'') + ISNULL(ColumnB,'')
```

You can control growing the transaction log with:
(this is from memory so may have syntax error(s))

```
select 1
while (@@rowcount > 0)
begin
    UPDATE top(10000) TableA 
    SET   ColumnC  = ISNULL(ColumnA,'') + ISNULL(ColumnB,'') 
    WHERE ColumnC <> ISNULL(ColumnA,'') + ISNULL(ColumnB,'') 
end
```

[Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql)

Computed column is a virtual column unless it is persisted.  So if you don't persist then there is no extra time to load ColumnA and ColumnB.  Select on ColumnC will be slower as it is computed on the fly.

If ColumnC is persisted will be like the update but done on the fly when ColumnA or ColumnB are inserted or updated.

As stated in comments a computed column is consistent.  An update is only consistent up to the last time the command was run.